# v-show within a v-for loop - show only clicked option

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I have a v-for loop set up there is a show button within the loop, when I click this, at the moment it opens all the hidden divs, I want it to open only the relevant one thats clicked. Maybe there is another way to do this or a better way I have been reading that v-show might net be suited to be used inside a loop.

```
<div id="app" class="container">

        <form>
          <div v-for="item in filterOptions" :class="{ activeclass: isActive }">
            <dl>
              <dt>
                <!--- click to show --->
                <button @click="toggle(item)" @click.self.prevent>{{item.name}}</button>
              </dt>

              <!--- show this --->
              <dd v-show="isActive" :id="item.name">
                 <button v-for="option in item.values" v-on:click="option.selected = !option.selected" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" :class="{'active' : option.selected}">
                   {{option.name}}
                </button>
              </dd>
            </dl>
          </div>
        </form>

        <div v-for="item in products">
            <div>
              <h5>
                {{item.name}}
              </h5>
              <h6>{{item.region}}</h6>
              <a>View</a>
            </div>
        </div>

  </div>

var main = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    products: [
      {
        name: "davy",
        region: "Highland",
        category: "Single Cask"
      },
      {
        name: "bill",
        region: "Islay",
        category: "New releases"
      },
      {
        name: "shena",
        region: "Highland",
        category: "Remarkable Regional Malt"
      }
    ],
    filterOptions: [
      {
        name: 'Region',
        isActive: false,
        values: [
          {
            name: 'Highland',
            selected : false
          },
          {
            name: 'Speyside',
            selected : false
          },
          {
            name: 'Islay',
            selected : false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Price',
        isActive: false,
        values: [
          {
            name: '£1-50',
            selected : false
          },
          {
            name: '£51-100',
            selected : false
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Category',
        isActive: false,
        values: [
          {
            name: 'Single Cask',
            selected : false
          },
          {
            name: 'Remarkable Regional Malt',
            selected : false
          },
          {
            name: 'New releases',
            selected : false
          }
        ]
      }
    ],

    isHidden: true,
    isActive: false

  },

  methods: {
    toggle: function () {
       this.isActive = !this.isActive;
     }
  }
})
```

Comment: You can use style bindings to toggle the css `display` property for the element you click on. It would toggle between whatever style display you're using (i.e., inline-block, flex, grid) and `none` to hide it. More guidance can be found here https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuejs-access-v-for-variable-in-v-bind-style/8732/2

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you

```js
window.onload = function() {
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
 data: {
    products: [
      {
        name: "davy",
        region: "Highland",
        category: "Single Cask"
      },
      {
        name: "bill",
        region: "Islay",
        category: "New releases"
      },
      {
        name: "shena",
        region: "Highland",
        category: "Remarkable Regional Malt"
      }
    ],
    filterOptions: [
      {
        name: 'Region',
        isActive: false,
        values: [
          {
            name: 'Highland',
            selected : false
          },
          {
            name: 'Speyside',
            selected : false
          },
          {
            name: 'Islay',
            selected : false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Price',
        isActive: false,
        values: [
          {
            name: '£1-50',
            selected : false
          },
          {
            name: '£51-100',
            selected : false
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Category',
        isActive: false,
        values: [
          {
            name: 'Single Cask',
            selected : false
          },
          {
            name: 'Remarkable Regional Malt',
            selected : false
          },
          {
            name: 'New releases',
            selected : false
          }
        ]
      }
    ],

    isHidden: true,
    isActive: false,
      selectedName: ''

  },

  methods: {
    toggle: function (item) {
      this.selectedName = item.name
     }
  }
})
}
```

```css
.success {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>

<div id="app" class="container">

        <form>
          <div v-for="item in filterOptions" :class="{ activeclass: isActive }">
            <dl>
              <dt>
                <!--- click to show --->
                <button  v-on:click.prevent="toggle(item)">{{item.name}}</button>
              </dt>

              <!--- show this --->
              <dd :id="item.name" v-if="item.name == selectedName" v-bind:class="{'success': (item.name == selectedName)}">
                 <button v-for="option in item.values" v-on:click="option.selected = !option.selected" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" :class="{'active' : option.selected}">
                   {{option.name}}
                </button>
              </dd>
            </dl>
          </div>
        </form>

        <div v-for="item in products">
            <div>
              <h5>
                {{item.name}}
              </h5>
              <h6>{{item.region}}</h6>
              <a>View</a>
            </div>
        </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `activeitem` in data and set  `this.activeitem = item.name`in `toggle` method.

```
 toggle: function (item) {
         this.isActive  = !this.isActive;
         this.activeitem = item.name
     }
```

in HTML add `v-show="item.name == activeitem && isActive"`

```
<dd  v-show="item.name == activeitem && isActive" :id="item.name">
                 <button v-for="option in item.values" v-on:click="option.selected = !option.selected" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" :class="{'active' : option.selected}">
                   {{option.name}} 
                </button>
              </dd>
```

```js
var main = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  activeitem:null,
    products: [
      {
        name: "davy",
        region: "Highland",
        category: "Single Cask"
      },
      {
        name: "bill",
        region: "Islay",
        category: "New releases"
      },
      {
        name: "shena",
        region: "Highland",
        category: "Remarkable Regional Malt"
      }
    ],
    filterOptions: [
      {
        name: 'Region',
        isActive: false,
        values: [
          {
            name: 'Highland',
            selected : false
          },
          {
            name: 'Speyside',
            selected : false
          },
          {
            name: 'Islay',
            selected : false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Price',
        isActive: false,
        values: [
          {
            name: '£1-50',
            selected : false
          },
          {
            name: '£51-100',
            selected : false
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Category',
        isActive: false,
        values: [
          {
            name: 'Single Cask',
            selected : false
          },
          {
            name: 'Remarkable Regional Malt',
            selected : false
          },
          {
            name: 'New releases',
            selected : false
          }
        ]
      }
    ],

    isHidden: true,
    isActive: false

  },

  methods: {
    toggle: function (item) {
         this.isActive  = !this.isActive;
         this.activeitem = item.name
     }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="container">

        <form>
          <div v-for="item in filterOptions" :class="{ activeclass: isActive }">
            <dl>
              <dt>
                <!--- click to show --->
                <button @click="toggle(item)" @click.self.prevent>{{item.name}}</button>
              </dt>

              <!--- show this --->
              <dd  v-show="item.name == activeitem && isActive" :id="item.name">
                 <button v-for="option in item.values" v-on:click="option.selected = !option.selected" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" :class="{'active' : option.selected}">
                   {{option.name}} 
                </button>
              </dd>
            </dl>
          </div>
        </form>

        <div v-for="item in products">
            <div>
              <h5>
                {{item.name}}
              </h5>
              <h6>{{item.region}}</h6>
              <a>View</a>
            </div>
        </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: In your `toggle`-function you should check if `this.isActive === true` before setting `this.activeitem = item.name`.